# What's the proper way of checking non-inclusion in Python

Tags: python

In Python 3, is there a difference between using these two expressions?

`item not in list`

vs.

`not item in list`

Comment: Second one is negation of `item in list`, so its equivalent to `not (item in list)`. First one is one expression, from what I understand, and it is more intuitive and I think faster.

Comment: @Marcin I doubt there's any performance difference. They both have to do the exact same work internally: loop through the list until they find a match.

Comment: It makes very little difference which one you use. Performance will be the same, both are equally as readable. Generally not worth splitting hairs over this.

Answer (score 2):

The two expressions are equivalent, but the first one is more idiomatic, so it's preferred.

Comment: The precedence chart you linked puts `not` at a lower precedence than `in`.

Comment: Oops, saw `not in` and read it as `not`.

Answer (score 0):

`item not in list` is being mentioned in the Python documentation and `not item in list` is not.
Which means that it is better to use `item not in list`.